# Two $5$-member panels are made out of a group of $10$ people. What is the probability the $4$ friends end up in the same panel?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Question:

A panel of ten members, responsible for deciding conflicts of any nature, will be divided into two groups of five members each, both with equal authority to decide conflict situations. No member can participate in both classes, and all members have an equal role in each class. It is known that, of the ten members, André, Luzia and Christian and Alex are friends. If members are randomly distributed among the two classes, what is the probability that André, Alex, Luzia and Cristiano are all in the same class?

My solution:

The total number of ways to divide a group of $10$ people into two groups of $5$ is the number of combinations of $10$ items taken $5$ at a time, which is denoted as $C(10,5)$. Then, we choose $4$ specific members to be in one class, and then we choose $1$ additional member from the remaining $6$ to join them, making a group of $5$. This can be calculated using $C(6,1)$. Finally, since we have two groups, we multiply the whole expression by $2$, giving:
$\frac{2 \cdot C(6,1)}{C(10,5)}$, which is equal to $4.76\%$.

Real Answer: 2.38%

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach which confirms OP's answer.
There are two groups of $5$ slots each for people. $\small{\square\square\square\square\square\quad\square\square\square\square\square}$

The first friend can go to any slot, and the rest can be successively put in slots available in that group with the last slot to one of $6$ "others" to give

$Pr = \frac49\frac38\frac 27\frac66 =\frac1{21}, \approx 4.76\%$

**PS:** $\mathtt{To\; clear\; doubts\; of\; Mahendra\; Varma}$

In the normal multinomial coeffficient approach,
$\dbinom{n}{n_1,n_2, ...n_k}$ can be interpreted as putting  $n_1$ in team $1$ (not in *any* team), $n_2$ in team $2...\;$ etc with the  **people getting labeled by the team they are put into.**

The problem with this is that with equal numbers in two teams, $\binom{10}{5,5}$   would count each *named* person once in team $A$ and once in team $B$, and thus double count.

My approach has circumvented spending thought on this issue.

Comment: You are supposed to divide by 2 as the first friend entering any slot of the first group is the same as him entering the corresponding slot in the second group. You are re-counting the cases.

Comment: @MahendraVarma: I have adde a PS to clear your doubt.

Answer (score -1):

The questions says

> ...both with equal authority to decide conflict situations...

This means both groups are considered to be identical. Therefore, the friends being in Group A is the same as them being Group B. This way we get 2.38%

Comment: The group's authority is one thing, and group's composition an entirely different thing.

Comment: I fail to understand how you will differentiate the case Group A having a set of people and the case where the same set is in Group B, if there is no naming Group A and Group B. The question has never mentioned distinct groups, they are just divided

Comment: The groups have automatically got distinguished as the "friends" group anf the "others"

Comment: Exactly my point, and when you try to exchange both groups so do the names of groups.. 'friends' become 'others' and 'others become 'friends'. It is the same case.
You are saying ABCDE FGHIJ is different from FGHIJ ABCDE... they aren't.

Comment: I didn't realise that the groups were labelled (I still don't understand how we inferred that). But, I do understand that you are right

Comment: I have redrafted the PS for greater clarity. You can now clearly see how the groups are labeled.

Comment: Appreciate the efforts... Thank You for your time

Comment: Glad to be of help ! $\;\;$ :)